# What is the usefulness of using throw? and in catch?

Tags: exception

From what I understand `throw` causes an exception. 
It looks like it can be used to test your `catch` exception.

- What are the benefits/uses for it?  Why would you want to purposely cause an exception?
- Why use `throw` in `catch`? Seems like it catches the exception just to cause an exception again.

  ```
  try
  {
      //blah
  }
  catch
  {
      throw; 
  }
  ```

Comment: Is this homework - and are you talking about C++ or another language

Comment: I don't think you understand it right. Pick up a good book about your favourite programming language and spend some time with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`throw;` *rethrows* the current exception.  It's used for when you want to catch an exception and do some handling of your own, but otherwise still want the exception to propagate more-or-less as if you never caught it.

The difference (in languages that let you just say `throw;`, like C#) is that when you rethrow an exception, the original stack trace remains mostly intact.  (It includes the line where you rethrew the exception rather than the line where the exception occurred in the corresponding `try` block, but otherwise the whole stack trace is preserved.)  If you say `throw the_exception_you_caught;`, it's usually treated as if you threw a brand new exception from right there -- the existing stack trace gets obliterated and a new one starts from that point.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are mechanism for error handling. For instance, you may throw an exception to indicate that a webservice call has timed out, or bad input as been provided to a method. The idea is that calling code knows how to deal with these exceptions and handles them gracefully — perhaps fixing what's wrong in the case of bad input (by prompting the user) or by trying a callout a second time.

A `catch` block is where you do your handling of the error, and in certain scenarios you may want to do some local cleanup in the method running, but then you still need to report the error to calling methods, so you throw the exception once more (or throw a different, maybe more generic or specific exception) which you then handle in your calling code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

You can do this to, for example, log something and give the exception back to the calling method / assembly.

You can handle the exception and signals the caller that a exception is happend instead of return a `boolean` that indicates if the method has success.

This is useful for unit tests and more.

#### Sample

```
try
{
    //blah
}
catch
{
    // log exception to textfile of database
    throw; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern in .Net code.  It's used when the caller wants to either log, wrap or react to an exception and then pass it back up to the caller.  For example

```
try { 
  SomeFunction(); 
} catch { 
  CloseMyResource();
  throw;
}
```

The advantage of `throw` vs `throw exceptionVariable` is that `throw` preserves the original stack trace.  The next person to catch the exception sees the original stack trace.  This is essentially for tracking down errors in deep call stacks.

Comment: You would typically have Resource clean up in a `finally` clause.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk not always. It's very possible you have a scenario where you only need to cleanup if there is an error.  Consider if you create a resource and an exception happens during a handoff / initialization routine.  When it succeeds the created object owns the resource, on error / exception you need to clean it up.

Comment: True. Most of the time it's in the finally. I guess depends on the practices of the particular shop.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk the more common scenario is definitely the finally. But that's only useful when the resource always needs to be destroyed. In cases of resource hand off the resource onyl needs to be destroyed on error because the hand off failed

Answer (score 1):

You would re-throw the same exception if you wanted to do some logging here or some clean up but would like to still have the calling functions further up the call stack to have to handle that same exception.

A more typical use would be:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (EmailException ex) {
    SMS.AlertError("Email is not working", ex);
    throw;
}
```

If you `throw ex` you will have stripped out information such as the call stack from the exception.

The some function above that would:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    WorkFlowProblems.Add(new OrderNotSentException("Email did not work", ex));
    View.ShowError("Could not send order!");
}
```

Here you make a new exception and set it's "inner exception" to be original cause. This is a good way for multi-part systems to have the right level of information about what went wrong and at what level.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be better to think of a throw as your informed reaction to an exception in your code rather than the cause. Semantics I know but it helps.

You throw a different exception in a catch to add information. Your converting what may be a generic OS exception into one meaningful to your application. e.g. Out of memory exception may be caught and a new exception with the out of memory as the inner exception be throw saying something like "Error while computing the answer to life the universe and everything". More useful that just an out of memory exception.

You may use a 'throw' on its own as a rethrow. The catch allows you to do something before rethrowing. If we are talking C# check out 'finally'.

When something really bad happens, that ought not happen, then you can abort and inform the caller by throwing an exception. It means that you do not need to have every method returning result codes and every caller testing fault/success codes. It also nicely abstracts who handles such 'exceptions' or even if you just leave it to the OS.

Quick answer ... it makes your code simpler and gives you better control of aborting and handling exceptions. Think of it as a messaging/abort system.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this preserves the stack trace. In your example, it's not useful, however, you could catch the exception, log it and then rethrow so that the exception bubbles up to be handled by code higher up.

Answer (score 0):

The place where throwing exception (in my opinion) is MOST useful is when you want to create an instance of a new object and there's some possibility that the instance needs to fail in creation, in which case the instance can be made to remain null (since constructors don't "return" anything... so for example...

Foo foo = new Foo();//

//at this line foo may or may not be the exact thing you want it to be, depending on whatever conditions made the creation of Foo possible.

So, Foo throws an exception you can do this:

```
Foo foo = null;
try{
  foo = new Foo();
}catch(FooException fe){
  //here you can find out if Foo didn't get instantiated as you wanted it to
}

//and here you can test if foo is still null.
```